# React Router Dynamic Links in Navbar

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Im trying to build a nav bar where the links change depending on the window.location.pathname. However the links aren't re-rendering when the page changes. What is the simplest way to make this work?

```
          {window.location.pathname === '/SavedRecipes' ? (
            <Button
              onClick={() => setSearchQuery('')}
              color="inherit"
              to="/"
              component={RouterLink}
            >
              Search
            </Button>
          ) : (
            <Button
              onClick={() => setSearchQuery('')}
              color="inherit"
              to="/SavedRecipes"
              component={RouterLink}
            >
              Saved Recipes
              <BookmarkBorderIcon />
            </Button>
          )}
```

any help would be much appreciated as I am new to React and sorry in advance if it's a stupid question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `react-router-dom's` `pathname` from `useLocation` hook.

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom"

// 
const { pathname } = useLocation();

const Component = () => {

    return (
        {pathname === '/SavedRecipes' ? (
        ....
        )}
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I was hoping it would be something as simple as this! much appreciated!

Comment: @Wekiban consider accepting the answer so that other's benefit too.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use one Button like this:

```
  const pathnameIsSavedRecipes =  window.location.pathname === '/SavedRecipes'

  <Button
    onClick={() => setSearchQuery("")}
    color="inherit"
    to={pathnameIsSavedRecipes ? "/" : "/SavedRecipes"}
    component={RouterLink}
  >
    {pathnameIsSavedRecipes ? "Search" :  "Saved Recipes"}
    {!pathnameIsSavedRecipes && <BookmarkBorderIcon />}
  </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not already using "react-router" you can install it using:

```
yarn add react-router
```

then in a React.Component within a "Route", you can call:

```
this.props.location.pathname
```

or

If you are using react router you might find useful checking out useLocation and useHistory hooks. Both create an object with a pathname attribute you can read and are useful for a bunch of other stuff. Here's a youtube video [explaining react router hooks][1]

Both will give you what you need (without the domain name):

```
import { useHistory ,useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
const location = useLocation()
location.pathname

const history = useHistory()
history.location.pathname
```